# bash script: check if a variable is in [A-Z]

Tags: bash, shell-script

How do I check if a variable is in [A-Z]?

I want to achieve something like this:

```
read var

while [ $var in [A-Z] ]
do
 #code here
done
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is `$var` a single character or do you want to test that it contains only letters?

Comment: And are you intending to loop over multiple inputs?

Answer (score 10):

In bash, you can use a pattern on the right hand side of a `==` in a `[[ ... ]]`:

```
read var
LC_ALL=C # Turn off locale.
if [[ $var == [A-Z] ]] ; then
    echo yes
fi
```

Turning off locale might be needed if you do not want `y` to be in `A-Z`.

Answer (score 6):

The simple one liner would be:

```
re='[a-zA-Z]'; if [[ Z =~ $re ]]; then echo "Match"; else echo "No match"; fi
```

The full script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

re='[a-zA-Z]'
read -p "Enter a char or string > " var

if [[ "$var" =~ $re ]]; then
    echo "Entered string matches."
else 
    echo "Entered string does not match";
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `$var` is a single character:

If you used `case` then it would be portable to any `sh` shell:

```
case "$var" in [A-Z]) thing_to_do_here ;; esac
```

or even

```
case "$var" in [[:upper:]]) thing_to_do_here ;; esac
```

For those of you who do not like unbalanced parens: It's ok to write

```
case "$var" in ([[:upper:]]) thing_to_do_here ;; esac
```

Comment: This checks whether at least one character is in the range. I'd have guessed the OP wants all characters to match, perhaps only allowing single-character strings.

Comment: You could do `case $var in *[!A-Z]* | ??) exit 255;; esac` to reject invalid strings (the second alternative rejects anything longer than a single character, take it out if you don't want that; and the `exit` might be too draconian).

Comment: @tripleee That's a matter of interpretation of the question, related to terdon's query to the question itself. I'm assuming a single character.

Comment: Then the wildcards around the condition are wrong. If other code forces the input to be a single character, it doesn't matter, but what the cooe actually does is to check that there is at least one matching character in a potentially longer string.

Comment: @tripleee Almost a year since I wrote that answer. But I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but you can use **grep** and do something like this:

```
read var
if grep -q "[a-z]" <<< "$var"
then
    <code>
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on Bash's regular expressions:

```
remainder=$(tr -d A-Z <<<$var)
while [ ! -z $remainder ];do
    read -p "Invalid value entered. Please try again." var
    remainder=$(tr -d A-Z <<<$var)
done
```

I'm guessing you want to use this for input validation.